# Special flexbox layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to accomplish the following layout:

[image]

My first thought is to use `flexbox` to achieve this layout. I currently have the following HTML:

```
<section>
   <div class"item">box1</div>
   <div class"item">box2</div>
   <div class"item">box3</div>
   <div class"item">box4</div>
   <div class"item">box5</div>
</section>
```

How can I achieve the desired layout with my HTML? I can add line break div elements in between items like this as well:

```
<div class"break"> </div>
```

Unfortunately I am still not able to achieve the required layout. Please help

Comment: you will have better luck with CSS grid

Comment: One-dimensional layout: Flexbox; two-dimensional layout: Grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple CSS-grid based approach would be to use a "[template of named grid areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas#Naming_a_grid_area)".

CSS grid allows for named areas, which dictate the placement of children based on the `grid-area` of those grid children. In the case of your requirements, a template based on named areas could be defined as:

```
grid-template-areas: 
"a a b b c c" 
". . e f . .";
```

These template areas work by causing:

- child elements with `grid-area` of `a`, `b`, and `c` to occupy the top row of the template layout, where each spans two columns of the 6 column grid
- child elements with `grid-area` of `e` and `f` to occupy the bottom row of the template, at the third and fourth column respectively. The `.` on this row configuration specifies that no child apples to that area of the template

Note that template area strings can be written on the same line for the `grid-template-areas` property as shown below:

```css
section {
  /* Specify that CSS grid is to be used for layout of children */
  display: grid;
  /* Specify spacing between children */
  grid-gap:1rem;
  /* Wrap against six evenly spaced columns of this grid */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  /* Define the area names of the grid template */
  grid-template-areas: "a a b b c c" ". . e f . .";
}

section div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: a;
}

section div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: b;
}

section div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: e;
}

section div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: f;
}

section div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: c;
}

/* Optional aesthetics to better match your example */
div {
  background: darkgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class "item">box1</div>
  <div class "item">box2</div>
  <div class "item">box3</div>
  <div class "item">box4</div>
  <div class "item">box5</div>
</section>
```

#### Updates

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "a b c c d e" ". . f g . .";
}

section div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: a;
}

section div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: b;
}

section div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: c;
}

section div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: f;
}

section div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: g;
}

section div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: d;
}

section div:nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: e;
}

/* Optional aesthetics to better match your example */
div {
  background: darkgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class "item">box1</div>
  <div class "item">box2</div>
  <div class "item">box3</div>
  <div class "item">box4 lots of content causes uneven column distribution</div>
  <div class "item">box5</div>
  <div class "item">box6</div>
  <div class "item">box7</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but boxes layout is different, see box3 and box4 is under box2

Comment: @geoplous you're welcome - just updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: 1st time with grid,I always using flexbox! Can yo uplease add one box in front and another at the end? So the configuration will be (1),(2),(3 on top)(4 under)(5 under), (6),(7). Also I do not want equal boxes, but to be adapted according to content, possible? Thank you

Comment: @geoplous the grid is very powerful so it's worth learning :) just updated answer with the extra points your mentioned. Does that help?

Comment: Works perfect thank you. I suppose on small grids I just say display block to stack one above other.

Comment: You're welcome :) yup, or you could define another row for `grid-template-areas` to control how the stacking is laid out

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `CSS Grid` Instead:

[Complete Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Working Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "i1 i1 i2 i2 i3 i3" ". . i4 i5 . .";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6,1fr); /* to make all boxes same with */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.i1 {
  grid-area: i1
}

.i2 {
  grid-area: i2
}

.i3 {
  grid-area: i3
}

.i4 {
  grid-area: i4
}

.i5 {
  grid-area: i5
}

.item {
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: #7D7D7D;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  ;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.i4,.i5 { 
border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div class="item i1">box1</div>
  <div class="item i2">box2</div>
  <div class="item i3">box3</div>
  <div class="item i4">box4</div>
  <div class="item i5">box5</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but boxes layout is different, see box3 and box4 is under box2 see image at the post

Comment: I've added `border-radius` especially for box 4 & 5, to make the radius smaller than box 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox you can adjust the order of the element and rely on wrapping:

```css
section {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:center;
}
section > .item {
  width:calc(100%/3 - 10px);
  margin:5px;
}
section > .item:nth-child(3),
section > .item:nth-child(4){
  order:1;
  width:calc((100%/3 - 20px) /2);
}


/* Irrelevant styles */

section > .item {
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:10px;

}
```

```html
<section>
   <div class="item">box1</div>
   <div class="item">box2</div>
   <div class="item">box3</div>
   <div class="item">box4</div>
   <div class="item">box5</div>
</section>
```